# What word describes a policeman who is not wearing a uniform?

Tags: nouns, terminology

How do you describe a police officer on duty, who wears casual clothes because he/she doesn't want to disclose his/her identity?

Comment: You may want *undercover*, *incognito* or *disguised*. Please add context.

Comment: Chris Chen, saying "at his duty" is extremely unusual and awkward. It is much more common to say *on duty*. There is an example of it being used, at this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/duty_1?q=duty

Comment: Tristan is correct. I left it alone while editing simply because I didn't want to change even more than I did.

Comment: Chris Chen, that's good and easier to read, now. It would probably be more accurate to adjust the term *policeman* to *police officer* because, many parts of the world also have police women.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If the policeman is wearing everyday clothes as part of an assignment, if he or she is on duty at the moment and normally wears a uniform but not for this particular job, then I would say *undercover*. *Undercover* implies that the policeman is actively trying to hide the fact that they are police.

*Plainclothes* is usually used to describe officers who don't wear uniforms in general. For example, detectives tend to not wear uniforms, or so I gather from TV police shows. I admit I don't have much experience in this field.

If the policeman is simply at home and dressed normally, I would just say that they are *not in uniform*.

Finally, some other terms you might consider are (definitions from the Free Dictionary):

- [*mufti*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mufti)

> Civilian dress, especially when worn by one who normally wears a uniform.

- [*civvies*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/civvies)

> Civilian clothes.

Comment: Using the word *mufti* in this context, is unusual. Using *civvies* or *civilian clothes* is more common.

Comment: I never even knew about this meaning of ‘mufti’—never heard that used. I only know it as an Arabic title … and as a mildly derogatory term for people of Arabic descent in general.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet believe it or not, I picked that up when reading Asterix in Britain (translated into English) as a young child in the 80s. The translation was probably from the 70ies or earlier, I don't remember. The word was unknown to me but it has stuck. I can't find a reference showing the actual panel (though I remember it clearly) but you can see it mentioned in the annotations [here](http://asterix.openscroll.org/books/asterix_in_britain.html), page 32, panel 8.

Comment: Oh, I’ll believe that—I learnt many a learned, uncommon word from Disney cartoons (Donald Duck/Mickey Mouse, etc.) as a kid, like ‘Mammon’.

Comment: I remember "Mufti" from "Mufti day": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mufti_(dress)#Mufti_day

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: interesting — I (growing up in the UK in the 80’s/90’s) only knew it in the “non-uniform clothes” sense described above.  Where does it get used pejoratively?

Comment: Mufti is a very common word in India. People here use it on a regular day.

Comment: It's also useful to distinguish between "a plainclothes officer" and "an officer in plainclothes". The latter can be someone who generally works for the uniform branch, but is assigned to some detective work, or whatever.

Comment: Mufti used to be used extensively in the military. When someone was wearing civilian attire it was common to say they were in mufti.

Comment: 'Mufti' is one of the words that has entered English via British India of which there are scores in everyday use. A lot, in my experience, are unknown to Americans. Words like 'bungalow' ,meaning a single-story house, 'gymkhana' a small horse riding competition, usually for children, etc. Even the nickname for Britain, which every British soldier and ex-pat uses at some stage, 'Blighty' (re song 'Take me back to dear old Blighty') comes from the Hindi word meaning 'foreign parts'. Colloquialisms like 'let's have a "dekko" at your new car', meaning 'a look', is another from the sub-continent.

Comment: Mufti ('Military Uniform For Travelling Incognito') comes from British Army slang and used to refer specifically to the armed services, but I agree it has become naturally extended to anyone who habitually wears a uniform.

Answer (score 38):

In America and the UK the officer would be called [plainclothes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undercover#Plainclothes_law_enforcement)

From the Free Online Dictionary:

[plainclothes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plainclothes) - Wearing civilian clothes while on duty to avoid being identified as police or security

Comment: Lumberjack, people also say *plain clothes*, in the UK.

Comment: I'd use *plainclothesman* (the noun form).

Comment: @Lumberjack: Even in India, I've come across them being described as "Plainclothesmen"

Answer (score 5):

**Undercover agent**

> Being undercover is disguising one's own identity or using an assumed
>   identity for the purposes of gaining the trust of an individual or
>   organization to learn secret information or to gain the trust of
>   targeted individuals in order to gain information or evidence.
>   Traditionally it is a technique employed by law enforcement agencies
>   around the world and a person who works in such a role is commonly
>   referred to as an [**undercover
>   agent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undercover_operation).

The agent is still a police officer working on duty and may very well dress in civilian clothes in order to disguise his real identity.

[M.W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undercover) has this to say for **undercover**: *done or working in a secret way in order to catch criminals or collect information; "for months she's been an undercover agent pretending to be a drug dealer"*

Comment: 'Undercover agent' sounds a bit sinister to me. UK police forces are organised in two sections 'uniform branch', and 'plainclothes branch'. The ranking system is slightly different. the plainclothes officers have the letter D in front of their rank. Thus the lowest rank of uniformed officer is a PC (Police Constable). His plainclothes equivalent is a DC (Detective Constable). These appendages go all the way up the system through Sergeant, Inspector, Superintendent, and Chief Superintendent. When you get to Assistant Chief Constable the ranking system merges.  (cont'd)

Comment: Uniformed officers do on occasions wear plain clothes. If they need to go to visit a witness, for example, and the witness is sensitive about his neighbours seeing a uniformed police officer appearing at his house, then the policeman may agree to go in plain clothes. What type of clothes the plainclothes officers wear will very much depend on the type of work they are doing.

Comment: @WS2 This is an American term, and the first word I thought of when I read the OP's question. Yes, a plain clothes officer is a police officer who wears civilian clothes but the OP said:*"if he doesn't want to disclose his identity"*. Undercover fits the bill.

Comment: WS2, what you described as the 'plainclothes branch', is called CID, in the UK, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cid?q=CID

Comment: @Tristan Yes I have just looked it up and you are right. For some strange reason I thought the name Criminal Investigation Department (CID) had been abolished. The expression seems seldom used nowadays, in the way it once was.

Comment: WS2, maybe you just need to watch a few of the police documentary programmes that are so popular on television, now.

Comment: @Tristan I go back to the days of Dixon of Dock Green!

Comment: WS2, British policing has moved on just a bit, since then!

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, the most commonly-known form of undercover policing is the Drug Enforcement Agency's implementation of narcotics officers in areas with rapidly-growing illicit drug distribution. While some of these are cooperative citizens after being convicted of a posession-related misdemeanor, many are active police officers.  In either case they are commonly referred to by both sides of the "War on Drugs" as **narcs**, short for **narcotics informant**. And also, both the DEA and the users/distributors of illegal drugs use **snitch** and **rat** as slightly more derogatory synonyms to **narc**. The justification for referring to these individuals with degradation centers around the **narc**'s use of deceit and strategic exploitation of trust in the clear interest of either self-advancement or self-preservation.

The noun **spy** is worth mentioning. One can assume that an on-duty police officer, intentionally hiding his involvement in law enforcement, is engaged in some form of social manipulation with the purpose of obtaining private information. Perhaps the archetypal spy caricature perpetuated by numerous media franchises prevents us from using such an accessible and suitably-defined word as **spy** in a serious manner, but it takes very little time for the novelty of a word's invocation of ideative silliness to be outweighed by the word's simple practicality.

If none of these available nouns suffice, I have a more abstract suggestion. The noun **badge** could be used to describe an on-duty police officer intentionally not dressed in uniform.  One can imagine the actual policeman's badge - hidden snugly away in a wallet in a pocket - as symbolic of the man's identity as a cop.  It is also not derogatory, communicates the idea of a personified mark of honor, as in a badge of courage, and has the feature of communicating a shell of an identity, e.g. "Anyone can see the man is a **badge** yet you continue associate to with him, blinded by your emotions!"