# What is an expression for a priest not wearing official attire?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, religion

Is there an English expression for a priest or monk not wearing his religious attire? (any Christian doctrine, or even more general).

**Clarification**: I'm trying to say that someone *looks like* an Orthodox priest who's not wearing vestments, not find a term/expression for priests who have, for any reason, not been wearing theirs.

I didn't include the *Orthodox* part in the original question since I was looking for a more universal expression, not a religious term, Orthodox or not.

Comment: *Sans cassock*? *Lay togs*?

Comment: Closely related: [What word describes a policeman who is not wearing a uniform?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133538/what-word-describes-a-policeman-who-is-not-wearing-a-uniform)

Comment: In his *civvies*?

Comment: Well, "defrocked" comes to mind, but probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you mean while on duty or during his personal time?

Comment: @HotLicks- I think if he's been defrocked, then he's not a priest anymore.

Comment: I'm mainly looking for a way to describe a person (He looked like an Orthodox priest without his vestments).

Comment: I would call that a 'clerical error'.

Comment: Let's get the question straight.  Here is this man, not a priest, but wearing black suit, black shirt, hoping that he will be thought to be a priest?  (for some reason, honest or nefarious...)  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: How about "priestly appearance"?

Comment: Honestly your clarification seems confusing because it seems to turn the problem on its head and ask for the opposite of what the rest of the question seems to request.

Comment: _Out-of-frock_ might work.

Comment: Are you saying the man in question looked something like [this](http://www.saintandrewgoc.org/storage/site_graphics/misc_graphics/fr_george.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319216443952) but without the religious garments and regalia. Not all priests/vicars wear long beards, and some do choose not to wear a dog collar, the long black cassocks etc.

Comment: I also find the clarification a tad confusing. Wouldn't a priest without their professional attire look like any other person? What sort of special feature are you trying to describe? A kind face?

Comment: I'm with @maksimov. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, guys. choster's answer below gave me all I needed, I also edited the question again to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: An [undercover priest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt0Y39eMvpI) might be something completely different...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aside from a hair-splitting distinction among some Catholics (see below), there is no *official* term, and you will find a variety of choices:

- *[layman's clothes](https://books.google.com/books?id=GNWZgIL5ZCoC&lpg=PA620&ots=GeUDWg6drk&pg=PA620#v=onepage&q=layman's)* is probably the most obvious way to make a distinction between clothes worn by clerics and clothes worn by non-clerics.
- More formally, one could refer to *[lay dress](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/w/wsfh/0642292.0033.028/--taking-the-veil-clothing-and-the-transformation-of-identity)* or *[lay costume](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04419b.htm)*, as a neat parallel to *clerical* dress or costume.
- More generically, at least in American English, *[street clothes](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sd3byNeBdR4C&pg=PT760&lpg=PT760&dq=%22civilian+clothes;+street+clothes%22&source=bl&ots=lB-DLAmNMi&sig=4_sS7N-M00D00Le3KuVDXf1IZV0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JHTjVPWMCPfesAS8zoHQCg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage)* are the ordinary clothes people wear in public, as opposed to specialized garments such as sportswear or work uniforms.
- You could borrow the term *[civilian clothes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/civilian+clothes)*, in more casual usages; usually this term is used to contrast street clothes from a police or military uniform. The slang *[civvies](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/civvy)* may be suitable in some cases.
- As Josh61 has indicated, police who do not wear a uniform are *[plainclothes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plainclothes)* officers, or work *in plain clothes*.
- Rarer is conversation is *[mufti](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mufti#mufti-2)*, already mentioned by bib. According to the Online Etymology Dictionary, this meaning *[is from 1816, of unknown origin, perhaps from mufti's costume of robes and slippers in stage plays, which was felt to resemble plain clothes](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mufti)*.

In Catholicism, it depends on what you mean by religious attire. There are various [various types of clerical dress](http://www.shetlersites.com/clericaldress/) for different purposes, and while the customary daily dress is the [cassock](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/98299/cassock), in many countries, at least among [secular priests](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/what-is-the-difference-between-secular-priests-and-religious-priests), the cassock has been replaced by the clerical suit.

This is not a newfangled development. The clerical suit was long preferred in Britain in order to distinguish Catholics from their cassock-clad Anglican cohorts, and in the U.S., it was adopted at one or the other [Councils of Baltimore](http://www.archbalt.org/about-us/the-archdiocese/our-history/synods.cfm) as a [precaution](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ra1VbfD9r0C&pg=PT283&lpg=PT283)  amidst strong, sometimes violent anti-Catholicism in American society. But to some traditionalists, the cassock is the only acceptable public costume, and therefore the clerical suit is not "official" attire.

Comment: It is not uncommon, or used not to be, to see a vicar in suit or tweed jacket, but wearing a clerical collar. A few years ago my wife and I went on a cruise where the ship's chaplain (an Anglican) was also the port lecturer. During the day, and whilst giving his lectures he would be in normal holiday attire like the other passengers - open necked shirt etc. But on formal evenings when people dressed for dinner with DJ and black tie, he would wear his clerical collar - I think with a dinner jacket.

Comment: I'm also a fan of "out of uniform" - but it's more idiomatic than accurate.  I'm also not sure how common it is.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could say *[in mufti](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mufti#mufti-2)*

> Plain clothes worn by a person who wears a uniform for their job, such as a soldier or police officer:
>   *I was a flying officer in mufti*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: Is that American? Also, it doesn't seem very common in relation to clergymen, judging by Google searches.

Comment: Originates in the British Army, adopting an arabic word. More usually used for Army Officers out of uniform. The sense would be understood by many UK folks.

Comment: You mean a 'mufti' is not fur-lined headwear for the deep cold winter?

Comment: At my children's schools in the UK, "mufti" is used to describe clothes which are not school uniform.

Answer (score 4):

As an Anglican Priest, I generally use the term plain clothes. But rarely is it necessay to explain what I am wearing. Among friends and other clergy, I just say "I'm not wearing my Priestlies (Priestly attire) today." Or I say I'm  going "uncollared".
I'd imagine that this differs more than just by the country in which the expression is used. Like just about everything, people have their own quirks, mannerisms, habits and expressions.  I'd venture it differs by the person. I'm positive I've heard just about every phrase that can be strung together that means I'm not wearing my clerical vestments in just my local Parish.
If you're looking to describe a Priest in a more formal, rather than casual way, it would be proper to say that he was in layman's clothes or not attired in his clerical vestments.

Answer (score 3):

[Plainclothes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plainclothes) :

> - dressed in ordinary clothes and not a uniform while on duty.
> - ordinary clothes, as distinguished from uniform, as worn by a police detective on duty
>
>   - a plain-clothes policeman.

- [a plain clothes priest](https://books.google.it/books?id=XVktuDe1aHUC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=a%20plain%20clothes%20priest&source=bl&ots=TyZr5JEUht&sig=O19x7tymTF-aG9cwYClxd4QXGI8&hl=it&sa=X&ei=qWjjVIq8EMXUaszxgcAF&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=a%20plain%20clothes%20priest&f=false)
  ( Joyce's Finnegans Wake: The Curse of Kabbalah)

Answer (score 1):

Layman's attire or layman's clothes.  From "Martin Luther:  The Man and the Image," by Herbert David Rix:  "he (Luther)...changed his identity by putting on a layman's attire for his evenings out."  "John P. (a fellow Augustinian monk) ran off because he was guilty of shameful behavior that disgraced us all.  The police found him in layman's clothes in a brothel."

A Google search easily finds many other examples of these expressions in literature.

Comment: While your suggestion is certainly correct, the results are not that many - I'm hopefully looking for a more common phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider ***non-clerical clothes/attire***. (to emphasize that the context is related to priests/clergy).

For example, this expression appears in "Vatican Council II: The Conciliar and Postconciliar Documents" *By Austin Flannery*:

> It is forbidden to celebrate Mass or perform other sacred actions, such as the laying on of hands at ordinations, the administering of other sacraments or the giving of blessings, while wearing only a stole over **non-clerical clothes**.